# Can't remove old toilet water supply line

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I'm trying to replace my toilet's supply line, but my old supply line looks like it's soldered to the shut off valve. Do I need to replace the shut off valve? And I'm a beginner, so is it something I should have a professional do?
[image]

Comment: Possible the valve is solder to the copper pipe whit white paint on it.  Unlikely the supply pipe is soldered on, but you will need two wrenches.  One to hold the valve in place and one to turn the base of the supply pipe.

Comment: Also might be a one piece, so wrenches might not help.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate   Who came up with that stupid idea?  Don't answer probably some designer high on something thinking it would make life easier.

Comment: I think they call it “value engineering”, in other words, make it a little cheaper so your tract homebuilder will save 5 minutes per install without any consideration of future maintainability. You can guess my opinion on this…